# GKE system pods gke-metrics-agent OOMKilld

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have noticed our gke cluster system pods (gke-metrics-agent) running out of memory. I have tried to editing daemonset yaml file for increasing memory request  to 200Mi and memory limit 200Mi for it. However, it didn't not allow me to apply it. It recreated with default as it like before which is 50Mi.
[pod status image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Bmf.jpg)

Please help me to increase memory resource of gke-metrics-agent

Answer (score 5):

Generally `CrashLoopBackOff` indicates that a container is repeatedly crashing after restarting. You can follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#CrashLoopBackOff) to troubleshoot `CrashLoopBackOff` issues.

A possible workaround that would limit the OOM killing of the gke-metric-agent would be to increase the memory limit for the gke-metric-agent pods. This can be done by disabling GKE monitoring and to use a custom Metric Agent manifest to deploy the gke-metric-agent to the cluster. This will allow you to adjust the memory resources for the gke-metric-agent to stop it from being killed.

To do so, you can follow the steps below:

#### **1.** Disable GKE monitoring

```
CLUSTER=<cluster_name>
PROJECT=<project>
LOCATION=<location>
```

```
gcloud container clusters update $CLUSTER --zone=$LOCATION --project=$PROJECT --monitoring-service=none --logging-service=logging.googleapis.com/kubernetes
```

#### **2.** Use following configuration and run it with:

```
sed -u -e's/{{.ClusterName}}/'${CLUSTER}'/g' -e's/{{.Location}}/'${LOCATION}'/g' metrics-agent.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: gke-metrics-agent-conf
  namespace: default
data:
  gke-metrics-agent-config: |
    receivers:
      prometheus:
        use_start_time_metric: true
        config:
          scrape_configs:
          - job_name: "kubelet"
            scrape_interval: 60s
            static_configs:
            - targets: ["$KUBELET_HOST:10255"]
            metric_relabel_configs:
            - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
              target_label: gke_component_name
              replacement: "nodes/kubelet"
          - job_name: "kubelet-prober"
            scrape_interval: 60s
            static_configs:
            - targets: ["$KUBELET_HOST:10255"]
            metrics_path: /metrics/probes
            metric_relabel_configs:
            - source_labels: [__name__]
              regex: "prober_probe_total|process_start_time_seconds"
              action: keep
            - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
              target_label: gke_component_name
              replacement: "nodes/kubelet"
          - job_name: "addons"
            scrape_interval: 60s
            kubernetes_sd_configs:
            - role: pod
              namespaces:
                names:
                - kube-system
              selectors:
              - role: pod
                field: "spec.nodeName=$NODE_NAME"
            relabel_configs:
            - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name ]
              regex: ".*metrics"
              action: keep
            - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotationpresent_components_gke_io_component_name ]
              regex: true
              action: keep
            - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotationpresent_monitoring_gke_io_path, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_monitoring_gke_io_path ]
              regex: "true;(.*)"
              target_label: __metrics_path__
            - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_name ]
              target_label: pod
            - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name ]
              target_label: container
            - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_namespace ]
              target_label: namespace
            - source_labels: [ __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_components_gke_io_component_name ]
              target_label: gke_component_name
              replacement: "addons/${ARG1}"
            - source_labels: [ gke_component_name ]
              target_label: gke_component_name
              regex: "(.*)-(.*)"
              replacement: "${ARG1}_${ARG2}"
            - source_labels: [ gke_component_name ]
              target_label: gke_component_name
              regex: "(.*)-(.*)"
              replacement: "${ARG1}_${ARG2}"
          - job_name: "coredns"
            scrape_interval: 60s
            static_configs:
            - targets: ["$KUBELET_HOST:9253"]
            metric_relabel_configs:
            - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
              target_label: gke_component_name
              replacement: "nodes/coredns"
          - job_name: "coredns-nodecache"
            scrape_interval: 60s
            static_configs:
            - targets: ["$KUBELET_HOST:9353"]
            metric_relabel_configs:
            - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
              target_label: gke_component_name
              replacement: "nodes/coredns"
          - job_name: "node"
            scrape_interval: 60s
            static_configs:
            - targets: ["$KUBELET_HOST:10231"]
            metric_relabel_configs:
            - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
              target_label: gke_component_name
              replacement: "net/cluster/node"
      kubenode:
        endpoint: "http://$KUBELET_HOST:10255"
        scrape_interval: 60s
        cluster_name: {{.ClusterName}}
        location: {{.Location}}
        node_name: "$NODE_NAME"
        kubernetes_service_host: "$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST"
    exporters:
      stackdriver:
        endpoint: monitoring.googleapis.com:443
        skip_create_metric_descriptor: true
    processors:
      resource:
        type: "host"
        labels:
          cloud.zone: {{.Location}}
          host.name: "$NODE_NAME"
          k8s.cluster.name: {{.ClusterName}}
      metrics_export:
        common_prefix: "kubernetes.io/internal"
        detect_container_metrics: true

        allowed_labels:
        - "project"
        - "location"
        - "cluster_name"
        - "node_name"
        - "namespace"
        - "pod"
        - "container"
        export_map:
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/process_start_time_seconds":
            drop: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/kubelet_docker_operations_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "operation_type"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/docker_operations_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/kubelet_docker_operations_errors_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "operation_type"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/docker_operations_errors_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/kubelet_runtime_operations_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "operation_type"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/runtime_operations_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/kubelet_runtime_operations_errors_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "operation_type"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/runtime_operations_errors_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/rest_client_requests_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "code"
            - "method"
            - "host"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/storage_operation_duration_seconds":
            allowed_labels:
            - "volume_plugin"
            - "operation_name"
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/kubelet_network_plugin_operations_duration_seconds":
            allowed_labels:
            - "operation_type"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/network_plugin_operations_duration_seconds"
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/storage_operation_errors_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "volume_plugin"
            - "operation_name"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/storage_operation_status_count":
            allowed_labels:
            - "volume_plugin"
            - "operation_name"
            - "status"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/kubelet/prober_probe_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "container"
            - "namespace"
            - "pod"
            - "pod_uid"
            - "result"
            - "probe_type"
            export_as_int: true
            is_container_metric: true


        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/process_start_time_seconds":
            drop: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_cache_drops_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "server"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/cache_drops_total"
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_cache_hits_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "server"
            - "type"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/cache_hits_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_cache_misses_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "server"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/cache_misses_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_cache_prefetch_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "server"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/cache_prefetch_total"
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_cache_size":
            allowed_labels:
            - "server"
            - "type"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/cache_size"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_dns_request_count_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "family"
            - "proto"
            - "server"
            - "zone"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/dns_request_count_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_dns_request_duration_seconds":
            allowed_labels:
            - "server"
            - "zone"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/dns_request_duration_seconds"
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_dns_request_type_count_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "server"
            - "type"
            - "zone"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/dns_request_type_count_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_dns_response_rcode_count_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "rcode"
            - "server"
            - "zone"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/dns_response_rcode_count_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_forward_healthcheck_failure_count_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "to"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/forward_healthcheck_failure_count_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_forward_request_count_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "to"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/forward_request_count_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_forward_request_duration_seconds":
            allowed_labels:
            - "to"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/forward_request_duration_seconds"
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_forward_response_rcode_count_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "rcode"
            - "to"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/forward_response_rcode_count_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_forward_sockets_open":
            allowed_labels:
            - "to"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/forward_sockets_open"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_health_request_duration_seconds":
            allowed_labels: []
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/health_request_duration_seconds"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/coredns_panic_count_total":
            allowed_labels: []
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/dns_panic_count_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/nodecache_setup_errors_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "errortype"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/nodes/coredns/nodecache_setup_errors_total"
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/net/cluster/node/process_start_time_seconds":
            drop: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/net/cluster/node/conntrack_entries":
            allowed_labels: []
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/net/cluster/node/conntrack_error_count":
            allowed_labels:
            - "type"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/net/cluster/node/num_inuse_sockets":
            allowed_labels:
            - "protocol"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/net/cluster/node/num_tw_sockets":
            allowed_labels: []
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/net/cluster/node/socket_memory":
            allowed_labels: []
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/addons/kubedns/process_start_time_seconds":
            drop: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/addons/kubedns/skydns_skydns_dns_request_count_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "system"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/addons/kubedns/skydns_dns_request_count_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/addons/kubedns/skydns_skydns_dns_request_duration_seconds":
            allowed_labels:
            - "system"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/addons/kubedns/skydns_dns_request_duration_seconds"
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/addons/kubedns/skydns_skydns_dns_response_size_bytes":
            allowed_labels:
            - "system"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/addons/kubedns/skydns_dns_response_size_bytes"
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/addons/kubedns/skydns_skydns_dns_error_count_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "system"
            - "cause"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/addons/kubedns/skydns_dns_error_count_total"
            export_as_int: true
        - "kubernetes.io/internal/addons/kubedns/skydns_skydns_dns_cachemiss_count_total":
            allowed_labels:
            - "cache"
            export_name: "kubernetes.io/internal/addons/kubedns/skydns_dns_cachemiss_count_total"
            export_as_int: true
    extensions:
      observability:
        endpoint: monitoring.googleapis.com:443
        prefix: "kubernetes.io/internal/addons/gke_otelsvc"
        resource:
          type: "k8s_container"
          labels:
            location: {{.Location}}
            cluster_name: {{.ClusterName}}
            pod_name: "$POD_NAME"
            namespace_name: "$POD_NAMESPACE"
            container_name: "gke-metrics-agent"
    service:
      extensions:
      - observability
      pipelines:
        metrics/kube:
          receivers:
            - kubenode
          exporters:
            - stackdriver
        metrics/prom:
          receivers:
            - prometheus
          processors:
            - resource
            - metrics_export
          exporters:
            - stackdriver
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: gke-metrics-agent
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  annotations:
    apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/allowedProfileNames: runtime/default
    apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/defaultProfileName: runtime/default
    kubernetes.io/description: Policy used by the gke-metrics-agent addon.
    seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/allowedProfileNames: runtime/default,docker/default
    seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/defaultProfileName: docker/default
  name: gce.gke-metrics-agent
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: 'true'
spec:
  privileged: false
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  volumes:
  - 'hostPath'
  - 'secret'
  - 'configMap'
  allowedHostPaths:
  - pathPrefix: /etc/ssl/certs
  hostNetwork: true
  hostIPC: false
  hostPID: false
  runAsUser:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
  seLinux:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
  fsGroup:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: gke-metrics-agent
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - policy
  resourceNames:
  - gce.gke-metrics-agent
  resources:
  - podsecuritypolicies
  verbs:
  - use
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: gke-metrics-agent
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: gke-metrics-agent
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: gke-metrics-agent
  namespace: default
---
# linux deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: gke-metrics-agent
  namespace: default
  labels:
    k8s-app: gke-metrics-agent
    component: gke-metrics-agent
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: gke-metrics-agent
      component: gke-metrics-agent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: gke-metrics-agent
        component: gke-metrics-agent
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoExecute
        operator: Exists
      - effect: NoSchedule
        operator: Exists
      hostNetwork: true
      serviceAccount: gke-metrics-agent
      containers:
      - name: gke-metrics-agent
        image: "gcr.io/gke-release/gke-metrics-agent:0.1.3-gke.0"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 50Mi
            cpu: 3m
          limits:
            memory: 70Mi
        env:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: KUBELET_HOST
          value: "127.0.0.1"
        - name: ARG1
          value: "${1}"
        - name: ARG2
          value: "${2}"
        - name: WINDOWS_JOB_ACTION
          value: "drop"
        command:
        - "/otelsvc"
        - "--config=/conf/gke-metrics-agent-config.yaml"
        - "--metrics-level=NONE"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: gke-metrics-agent-config-vol
          mountPath: /conf
        - name: ssl-certs
          mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: gke-metrics-agent-conf
          items:
          - key: gke-metrics-agent-config
            path: gke-metrics-agent-config.yaml
        name: gke-metrics-agent-config-vol
      - name: ssl-certs
        hostPath:
          path: /etc/ssl/certs
---
# windows deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: gke-metrics-agent-windows
  namespace: default
  labels:
    k8s-app: gke-metrics-agent
    component: gke-metrics-agent
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: gke-metrics-agent
      component: gke-metrics-agent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: gke-metrics-agent
        component: gke-metrics-agent
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: windows
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoExecute
        key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
        operator: Exists
        tolerationSeconds: 300
      - effect: NoExecute
        key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
        operator: Exists
        tolerationSeconds: 300
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: node.kubernetes.io/os
        operator: Equal
        value: windows
      serviceAccount: gke-metrics-agent
      containers:
      - name: gke-metrics-agent
        image: "gke.io/gke-release/gke-metrics-agent-windows:0.3.1-gke.2"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 5m
            memory: 200Mi
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
        env:
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: KUBELET_HOST
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.hostIP
        - name: KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST
          value: "kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local"
        - name: ARG1
          value: "${1}"
        - name: ARG2
          value: "${2}"
        - name: WINDOWS_JOB_ACTION
          value: "keep"
        command:
        - "c:\\otelsvc.exe"
        - "--config=/conf/gke-metrics-agent-config.yaml"
        - "--metrics-level=NONE"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: gke-metrics-agent-config-vol
          mountPath: /conf
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: gke-metrics-agent-conf
          items:
          - key: gke-metrics-agent-config
            path: gke-metrics-agent-config.yaml
        name: gke-metrics-agent-config-vol
```

*NOTE: You can edit the memory limit for the linux deployment as per your requirements.*

#### **3.** To revert the changes do the following

- Remove the DaemonSets and the config by either running

```
sed -u -e's/{{.ClusterName}}/'${CLUSTER}'/g' -e's/{{.Location}}/'${LOCATION}'/g' metrics-agent.yaml | kubectl delete -f -
```

OR

```
    kubectl delete ds gke-metrics-agent
    Kubectl delete ds gke-metrics-agent-windows
    kubectl delete cm gke-metrics-agent-conf
    kubectl delete sa gke-metrics-agent
```

- Reenable monitoring in your cluster

```
gcloud container clusters update $CLUSTER --zone=$LOCATION --project=$PROJECT --monitoring-service=monitoring.googleapis.com/kubernetes --logging-service=logging.googleapis.com/kubernetes
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this label in your nodes and it will increase the memory resource limit from 50Mi to 70Mi of gke-metrics-agent pods.

```
kubectl label node/NODENAME cloud.google.com/gke-metrics-agent-scaling-level=20 --overwrite
```

Comment: You can label it with different sizes: 10,20,50,100,200,500. you can view that by getting the daemon sets in kube-system

Answer (score 2):

Use the below command

`kubectl label node/NODENAME cloud.google.com/gke-metrics-agent-scaling-level=20 --overwrite`